# res.send not working when trying to fetch data

Tags: node.js

I am trying to implement update using node js , what i am expecting is when i click on update link in a particular row on my page the corresponding record should get populated in one of my field set defined. But looks like res.send(docs) is not sending the data . Below is part of my code

My field set defined in index.jade

```
    // ADD USER
    h2 Add User
    #addUser
        fieldset
            input#inputUserName(type='text', placeholder='Username')
            input#inputUserEmail(type='text', placeholder='Email')
            br
            input#inputUserFullname(type='text', placeholder='Full Name')
            input#inputUserAge(type='text', placeholder='Age')
            br
            input#inputUserLocation(type='text', placeholder='Location')
            input#inputUserGender(type='text', placeholder='gender')
            br
            button#btnAddUser Add User
    // /ADD USER
```

Below is the part in users.js
    /*
     * Fetch to updateuser.
    */

```
router.get('/fetchdata/:id',function(req,res){
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('userlist');
    var userToUpdate = req.params.id;
    console.log('Here i am',userToUpdate);
    collection.find({'_id':userToUpdate},{},function(e,docs){
        console.log('entered find',docs); //here i can see the required data is 
        //getting printed
        res.json(docs);
        console.log('entered send',docs);   
     });
});
```

Below is the part in global.js which i have defined.

```
$('#userList table tbody').on('click', 'td a.linkupdateuser', updateUser);

function updateUser(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/users/fetchdata/' + $(this).attr('rel')
    }).done(function(data,response){

      console.log('I am in global',data);

      if (response.msg === '') {
      }
      else {
         alert('Error: ' + response.msg);
      }

      $('#addUser fieldset input#inputUserName').val(data[0]['username']);
      $('#addUser fieldset input#inputUserEmail').val(data[0]['email']);
      $('#addUser fieldset input#inputUserFullname').val(data[0]
         ['fullname']);
      $('#addUser fieldset input#inputUserAge').val(data[0]['age']);
      $('#addUser fieldset input#inputUserLocation').val(data[0]
         ['location']);
      $('#addUser fieldset input#inputUserGender').val(data[0]['gender']);
      $("#subbtn").val('Edit Product');
     });
}
```

Please let me know the glitch in the above code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your code so it is readable.

Comment: your server url is `/fetchdata/:id` while the url your calling via ajax is `/users/fetchdata/:id`

Comment: Routing here is defined in users.js rather than index.js , hence calling it along with users.

Comment: In your client-side code when you do `console.log('I am in global',data);` what does that show?

Comment: Also, these selectors `#addUser fieldset input#inputUserName` loop troublesome.  You can only have one element in the page with a given id value - this looks like you're repeating id values in your page.  That often leads to selector errors (where it picks the wrong element).  You should probably use a class name instead of an id.

Comment: both these lines ,console.log('entered find',docs); console.log('entered send',docs) print the correct data expected. But console.log('I am in global',data); doesnt get printed. That means my data is not coming from router to js